# Create Input fields dynamically in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I am working on an Angular 4.X project and I am trying to create some HTML input fields (mostly of type text) on button click. I am using Angular reactive forms and trying to achieve this using Angular FormArray. I have written the code on the plunker but it shows some error.

Following is the link for the plunk that I have created --
http://plnkr.co/edit/PCFD43GK91zo2ivQ9lf7?p=preview

For easy reference please find the code below --

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<hr>
              <div>  
                <form [formGroup]="orderForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(orderForm.value)">
                  <div>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="customerName"/>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                      <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name"/>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="description" placeholder="Item description"/>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="price" placeholder="Item price"/>
                    </div>
                    Chosen name: {{ orderForm.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value }}
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit">Save</button>
                  <button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add More</button>
                </form>
              <div>`,
})

export class App {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {  }

  public items:any[];
  public orderForm: FormGroup;



  ngOnInit() {
      this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        customerName: '',
        email: '',
        items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem()])
      });
  }

 createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      description: '',
      price: ''
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
  this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }

  public OnSubmit(formValue: any) {
        console.log(formValue);
    }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If anyone can figure out what is wrong with it, I will highly appreciate that.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44767953), could be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a getter for your orderForm items and your variable name for FormBuilder should be either 'fb' what you declared in your contructor or 'formBuilder' what you are using everywhere

[Fixed plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5tYX5A1a7niAeXFuxbsY?p=preview)

```
export class App {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {  }

  public orderForm: FormGroup;



  ngOnInit() {
      this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        customerName: '',
        email: '',
        items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem()])
      });
  }

 createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      description: '',
      price: ''
    });
  }

   get items(): FormArray {
    return this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  };

  addItem(): void {
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }

  public OnSubmit(formValue: any) {
        console.log(formValue);
    }

}
```

html code

```
<div>  
                <form [formGroup]="orderForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(orderForm.value)">
                  <div>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="customerName"/>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i = index;">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                      <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name"/>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="description" placeholder="Item description"/>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="price" placeholder="Item price"/>
                    </div>
                    Chosen name: {{ orderForm.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value }}
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit">Save</button>
                  <button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add More</button>
                </form>
              <div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. This helped.!!

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I use validation to the dynamically created fields ? I am doing the following but it throws error.

createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      FirstName: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z]")]],
      MiddleName: ['',[Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z]")]],
      LastName: ['',[Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z]")]],
    });
  }

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `private fb: FormBuilder` but after this trying to call `this.formBuilder.something`. Change it to `this.fb.something`

If it still does not work, try putting your code from `ngOnInit` to the constructor method directly.